# Winston logging with HAPI does not work

Tags: node.js, logging, hapi.js, winston

I have a project with Winston logging enabled and the project uses HAPI. I have the following code:

```
    logger.js
    ---------

    var winston = require('winston');
    winston.emitErrs = true;

    var logger = new winston.Logger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
                level: 'debug',
                json: false,
                colorize: true
            })
        ],
        exitOnError: false
    });

    module.exports = logger;
    module.exports.stream = {
      write: function(message, encoding){
          logger.info(message);
      }
    };

    server.js
    ---------

    var Hapi = require('hapi');
    var logger = require('./conf/logger.js');

    var server = new Hapi.Server({
    });

    server.connection({ 
      port: 3000
    });

    server.register([require('./modules/healthcheck.js'), require('vision')], (err) => {
      if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to load a plugin:', err);
      }
    });

    server.start(function () {
        logger.info('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
    });

    healthcheck.js
    --------------

    var logger = require('./conf/logger.js');

    var healthchkPlugin = {
      register: function (server, options, next) {
        server.route({
          method: 'GET',
          path: '/',
          handler: function (request, reply) {
            logger.info("health check api invoked");
            reply("gateway up and running");
          }
        });
        next();
      }
    }

    healthchkPlugin.register.attributes = {
      name: 'healthchkPlugin',
      version: '0.0.1'
    };

    module.exports = healthchkPlugin;
```

When I run server.js and hit the end point with a GET request, the console shows the following:

info: Server started at http://<>:3000

But I expected it to show the info statement specified in GET handler. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: @BrianJ.Miller Yes I did.